# error while trying to empty a directory

Tags: centos, ssh

I try to empty a folder (/var/lib/php/session/) with putty on ssh, but I does not work. I do not know what goes wrong.

This is the command I use:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/php/session/*
```

Every time I run this command, it hangs without returning.  Thanks

Comment: What is the error or output that is returned to you? This is a key piece of information....

Comment: No output. In putty there is just the green pointer. Nothing else.

Comment: So then what makes you think the command didn't work?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/rnlanr2d5/ this is what every time I use that command.

Comment: Are there lots of files in the directory? IF so, it may take the shell a long time to list them. Try using e.g. `find` instead of running rm directly.

Comment: there are millions of files. how to use the find command? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably some of those files are still in use by a running PHP process. You can use `lsof -f` to verify this.

Are (another assumption since you're not providing many details) you running a webserver (Apache, nginx, etc) from which the PHP scripts are served? In that case you can stop the webserver, try running your command again and then start the webserver again, but keep in mind that this wil break visitors' websessions since you're removing all session data.

Comment: I am running a webserver. (apache) I tried to turn it off and delete those file but still no success. I could not delete them.

Comment: What does the `lsof -f` command say? There could still be PHP processes running.

Comment: That command says a lot of things. I do not understand what it says... Should I look up for any thing in particular?

Comment: Try `lsof -f | grep /var/lib/php/session/`, if this returns any results there are still processes with open files in that directory.

Comment: It does not show any result.

Comment: But anyway, I can not delete the files inside it. How can this be possible?

Comment: What does `rm -rf -v /var/lib/php/session/*` say?

Comment: I just noticed that I do not get even a single result using that command even apache is turned on.

Comment: rm -rf -v /var/lib/php/session/* says nothing. Let me take a screenshot.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/rnlanr2d5/ here it is

Comment: I don't see a new prompt. Did the command actually end or is it still running. `/var/lib/php/session/` can grow very large, so it might take some time to delete all those files.

Comment: No, it did not end. I thought that it can delete everything inside that directory instantly because once I deleted a 500gb log file instantly using that command. Ok, so now I will leave it finish until it ends. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Size isn't relevant when deleting files, the number of files in the directory is.

Comment: ahaaa, I did not know that. So, when will that command delete all the files in that directory? The size of the directory is 1013mb. I do not know how many files are in there.